# DB queries not returning any results in Job

Tags: laravel

So, I'm working on an application that can create livestreams and I'm working on the functionality to remind users when they registered for a livestream the day before of the livestream. However, when i run the job i created for it, it seems to not retrieve anything for the database. I know the issue isnt in the emailing part because i tried only sending an email without any conditional logic first. I'm pasting my code for the Job below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Mail\EventReminderMail;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use \DateTime;
use \DateInterval;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class EventReminder implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Get time for right now + 24hrs
        $time = new DateTime();
        $time->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $time = $time->format('Y-m-d');
        var_dump($time);
        // dd($time);
        $nextLivestreams = DB::raw('SELECT `id` from livestreams WHERE startAt LIKE '.$time.'%')->get();
        var_dump($nextLivestreams);
        foreach ($nextLivestreams as $livestream) {
            $registeredUsers = DB::table('event_registrations')->select('email')->where('livestream_id', $livestream);
            foreach ($registeredUsers as $userEmail)
            {
                //send emails
                Mail::to('myemail')->send(new EventReminderMail());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting `$nextLivestreams` as a non empty collection of records. If not you can write the query statement as

```php
$nextLivestreams = DB::table('livestreams')
    ->where('startAt', 'like', $time . '%')
    ->get('id');
```

You have two issues in the statement
`$registeredUsers = DB::table('event_registrations')->select('email')->where('livestream_id', $livestream);`

- `->where('livestream_id', $livestream)`: comparing value of `livestream_id` with `$livestream` object`
- without appending `->get()` you don't get a collection, it would be an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`

The query statement for getting `$registeredUsers` should be

```php
$registeredUsers = DB::table('event_registrations')
    ->select('email')
    ->where('livestream_id', $livestream->id)
    ->get();

//dump($registeredUsers) to check the value
```

From performance point of view you could rewrite the handle method as

```php
public function handle()
{
    $time = now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d');

    $nextLivestreams = DB::table('livestreams')
        ->where('startAt', 'like', $time . '%')
        ->get('id');

    //Getting $registered Users outside foreach loop 
    //will result in a single database query 
    //instead of one database query per iteration of loop
    //when the query is done from within foreach loop
    $registeredUsers = DB::table('event_registrations')
        ->whereIn('livestream_id', $nextLivestreams->pluck('id')->toArray())
        ->get('email');
 
    foreach($registeredUsers as $user) {
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new EventReminderMail());
    }
}
```